# c Inter Process Communication compiling

Tags: c, compilation, ipc

I have the following code which is a `popen` script file but when I compile it I am getting an error. What is causing the problem or how I can get rid of the error?
The code:

```
#include    <sys/wait.h>
#include    <errno.h>
#include    <fcntl.h>
#include    "ourhdr.h"

static pid_t    *childpid = NULL;
                        /* ptr to array allocated at run-time */
static int      maxfd;  /* from our open_max(), {Prog openmax} */

#define SHELL   "/bin/sh"

FILE *
popen(const char *cmdstring, const char *type)
{
    int     i, pfd[2];
    pid_t   pid;
    FILE    *fp;

            /* only allow "r" or "w" */
    if ((type[0] != 'r' && type[0] != 'w') || type[1] != 0) {
        errno = EINVAL;     /* required by POSIX.2 */
        return(NULL);
    }

    if (childpid == NULL) {     /* first time through */
                /* allocate zeroed out array for child pids */
        maxfd = open_max();
        if ( (childpid = calloc(maxfd, sizeof(pid_t))) == NULL)
            return(NULL);
    }

    if (pipe(pfd) < 0)
        return(NULL);   /* errno set by pipe() */

    if ( (pid = fork()) < 0)
        return(NULL);   /* errno set by fork() */
    else if (pid == 0) {                            /* child */
        if (*type == 'r') {
            close(pfd[0]);
            if (pfd[1] != STDOUT_FILENO) {
                dup2(pfd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                close(pfd[1]);
            }
        } else {
            close(pfd[1]);
            if (pfd[0] != STDIN_FILENO) {
                dup2(pfd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
                close(pfd[0]);
            }
        }
            /* close all descriptors in childpid[] */
        for (i = 0; i < maxfd; i++)
            if (childpid[i] > 0)
                close(i);

        execl(SHELL, "sh", "-c", cmdstring, (char *) 0);
        _exit(127);
    }
                                /* parent */
    if (*type == 'r') {
        close(pfd[1]);
        if ( (fp = fdopen(pfd[0], type)) == NULL)
            return(NULL);
    } else {
        close(pfd[0]);
        if ( (fp = fdopen(pfd[1], type)) == NULL)
            return(NULL);
    }
    childpid[fileno(fp)] = pid; /* remember child pid for this fd */
    return(fp);
}

int
pclose(FILE *fp)
{
    int     fd, stat;
    pid_t   pid;

    if (childpid == NULL)
        return(-1);     /* popen() has never been called */

    fd = fileno(fp);
    if ( (pid = childpid[fd]) == 0)
        return(-1);     /* fp wasn't opened by popen() */

    childpid[fd] = 0;
    if (fclose(fp) == EOF)
        return(-1);

    while (waitpid(pid, &stat, 0) < 0)
        if (errno != EINTR)
            return(-1); /* error other than EINTR from waitpid() */

    return(stat);   /* return child's termination status */
}
```

The error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
/tmp/ccAoPlxN.o: In function `popen':
popen.c:(.text+0xd9): undefined reference to `open_max'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'popen' failed
make: *** [popen] Error 1
```

I am compiling it with the folowing file:

```
#
#Makefile pentru lucrarea de laborator Sisteme de Operare 8
#

CC=gcc
COMPILE.c=$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c
LINK.c=$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
LDLIBS=liblab.a

CFLAGS  = -Wall -O

LIB = liblab.a

TEMPFILES = core core.* *.o temp.* *.out typescript*

PROGS = pipe1 pipe2 popen2 myuclc popen1 add2 pipe4 \
        msgtool semtool shmtool semstat

AR = ar
LIBLAB = liblab.a
RANLIB = ranlib

OBJS = error.o  prmask.o

all:    ${PROGS}

lib:    ${OBJS}
    ${AR} rv ${LIBLAB} $?
    ${RANLIB} ${LIBLAB}


clean:
    rm -f ${PROGS} ${LIBLAB} ${TEMPFILES}
```

Comment: What compiler command are you using? It looks like you're compiling to an executable but the linker can't find a `main()` function.

Comment: @DanielSchütte I am compiling it using a make file. I droped that file above

Comment: C programs must have a `main` function which is where execution begins when the program is run

Comment: also, `popen` is a POSIX standard function so you should not write your own function of the same name unless you are perhaps porting code to a non-POSIX system (which is clearly not the case here)

Comment: Also the error message does not match the makefile, since the error message talks about a target called `popen` but the makefile does not have any such target (and in fact does not have instructions for any target except `lib`)

Comment: @M.M And what can I do in this case?

Comment: Stop trying to compile your own `popen`